# Relacionar listas índices em python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Boa tarde!

Tenho a lista:

```
a=[4,3, 1, 2, 3]
```

e a lista:

```
sub_ind_novo=[96, 7, 97, 23, 18]
```

E precisava de relacionar as listas obtendo o resultado:
no97. G1 #quando `sub_ind_novo` é **97**, o correspondente em a é **1**, por isso só imprime isto **1** vez 
Preciso que sejam impresso o elemento de sub_ind_novo o número de vezes do elemento correspondente em a.
(a partir daqui, quando toma valores diferentes de 1 em a não sei como fazer.. ou seja, o 1º elemento em a é 4, e o respetivo em sub_ind_novo é 96, logo devia aparecer 4 linhas deste valor na forma como escrevo aqui em baixo no exemplo de resultado)
O restante devia ficar nesta forma (exemplo de resultado):

```
no23. G1
no23. G2
no7. G1
no7. G2
no7. G3
no18. G1
no18. G2
no18. G3
no96. G1
no96. G2
no96. G3
no96. G4
```

E fiz o seguinte código mas não consigo fazer para as vezes em que a é diferente de **1**, ou seja, em que a é (**2**, **3**, **4** ou **5**)..

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==1:
        print ("no%d. G1 \n" %sub_ind_novo[i])

    elif:
        .....
        print ("no%d. G%d \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],))
```

Obrigada!

Comment: que linguagem e essa que voce fala?

Comment: voce poderia fazer uma analogia mais simples do seu problema?

Comment: Estou a trabalhar em python 2.7

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor. Quer saber quais os valores de `a` que são iguais a 1, e ir ao index respetivo onde os achou em  `sub_ind_novo`? Neste caso que apresentou quer retirar os valores `sub_ind_novo[11]` e `sub_ind_novo[7]` ?

Comment: já editei, diminuí o tamanho das listas para facilitar.
Não, a lista "a" é como fosse uma lista de ocorrencias dos respetivos valores de "sub_ind_novo", como tal deve imprimir o elemento de "sub_ind_novo" o número de vezes que o respetivo elemento em "a", tal como no exemplo de resultado. (o 96 tem que aparecer 4 vezes, na forma: G1, G2, G3, G4; o 23 duas vezes na forma: G1, G2, etc.. )

Comment: muito confuso, posta uma parte maior do código e tenta explicar melhor o seu problema

Comment: já consegui resolver, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser resolvido com poucas linhas de código:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [4, 3, 1, 2, 3]                                            
sub_ind_novo = [96, 7, 97, 23, 18]

# relacionamos as listas e ordenamos de acordo com a lista a                                                           
relacao = sorted(list(zip(sub_ind_novo, a)), key=itemgetter(1))

for rel in relacao:                                            
    for i in range(1, rel[1] + 1):                             
        print('no{0}. G{1}'.format(rel[0], i))
```

O resultado será exatamente o que você precisa:

```
no97. G1
no23. G1
no23. G2
no7. G1 
no7. G2 
no7. G3 
no18. G1
no18. G2
no18. G3
no96. G1
no96. G2
no96. G3
no96. G4
```

Answer (score 0):

veja se isso tambem pode ser util

```
a=[4,3, 1, 2, 3]
sub_ind_novo=[96, 7, 97, 23, 18]

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==1:
        print "no{}. G1 \n".format(sub_ind_novo[i])

    elif a[i] != 1:
        print "no{}. G{} \n".format(sub_ind_novo[i], a[i])
```

Output

```
no96. G4 

no7. G3 

no97. G1 

no23. G2 

no18. G3
```

Qual foi a solucão que resolveu a sua pergunta? se possivel compartilha conhecimento com a galera

Comment: Resolvi a minha questão assim:
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==1:
        print ("no%d. G1 \n" %sub_ind_novo[i])
    else:
        for j in range(1,a[i]+1):
            print ("no%d. G%d \n" %(sub_ind_novo[i],j))